# Slower search response in solr

Tags: solr, solrj

I have a collection with 3 shards containing 5M records, with 10 fields, index size on disk is less than 1 GB, the document has 1 long valued fields which need to be sorted in every query.

All the queries are filter queries with one range query filter, where sorting on the basis of long value has to be applied.

I am expected to get the response under 50 milliseconds(including elapsed time). however, the actual Qtime range from 50-100 ms while Elapsed time varies from 200-350 ms.

Note: I have used docValues for all the fields, configured newSearcher/firstSearcher. Still, I do not see any improvement in response.

What could be the possible tuning options?

Comment: How often are you updating the index? The sort order should be cached, but it might require upping your cache sizes because of the index size. How many rows are you returning from the result set? Are you paginating through the result set? Is there any difference between two queries being run after each other? What does your filters and query look like?

Answer (score 0):

Try to index those values.That may help.
I am not quite sure but you can give a try.